# Populate view page with Json object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following script in my site.master which should be popultating my textboxes based on item selected from dropdown in the same page.

```
$(function() {
    $("#vendorID").change(function() {
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();
        if(selectedItem != "New Vendor Id")
        {                
            $.getJSON(
                "<%=Url.Action("DropDownChange") %>/?dropdownValue=" + selectedItem,
                function(data) {
                    //$("#Data").html(data); 
                    $("#name").val(data.Name);
                }
            ); 
            $(document).ready(function() {                   
                $("#zip").val('');
            });
```

I am not getting no errors and I am not getting the textboxes populated...what could be my possible errors????

ASP.NET Code;

public JsonResult DropDownChange(string dropdownValue)
        // This action method gets called via an ajax request
        {
            //dropdownValue = "FR28406";

```
        if (dropdownValue != null && Request.IsAjaxRequest() == true)
        {

            paymentApplicationRefund  =
            cPaymentRepository.PayableEntity(dropdownValue);

            paymentApplicationRefund.Address1.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.Address2.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.Name.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.City.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.Contact.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.State.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.Zip.Trim();



           return Json(paymentApplicationRefund,"application/json");               
        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have too much `document.ready` there. One is sufficient. Also I would recommend you URL encoding your parameters:

```
$(function() {
    $('#vendorID').change(function() {
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();
        if(selectedItem != 'New Vendor Id') {
            $.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("DropDownChange") %>', { dropdownValue: selectedItem }, function(data) {
                $('#name').val(data.Name);
            }); 
            $('#zip').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Also because $.getJSON is sending a GET request you must ensure that your controller action authorizes it:

```
public ActionResult DropDownChange(string dropdownValue)
{
    return Json(new { Name = "foo bar" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that are going on in your approach that may contribute to your issues.  It's hard to say exactly what's going on, but here's some possibilities:

**"if(selectedItem != "New Vendor Id")" should refer to a value, not a string literal.**

You're creating a dependency that your drop down item always has those exact words in it for your code to work.  If this doesn't match, that could explain why it doesn't work.

```
<option value="">New Vendor ID</option>

...

if(selectedItem) {
//...
}
```

**Check your data being returned to your success function.  Does it contain a "d" parameter?**

If yes: http://encosia.com/2009/06/29/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/

**Check your MVC handler functions and verify that the code is actually being hit.**

Get a browser with a decent debugging tool (Chrome, FF+FireBug) and watch the packets on the "Network/Net" tab.  Are you getting back a 404 or 500 error?  That'd hint at an issue with your .NET code, not your JS.

Comment: I did get an error - 500 Internal Server Error. I am going to post my ASP.NET code.

Comment: If I had to guess, it's that one of your properties is null, which is throwing an error when you call ".Trim()" on it.  Really you shouldn't need to trim so much, and these errors can be revealed easily through debugging.